# How to get ordered list of items in cab archive?

Tags: windows, wix, cab

I have 182Mb uncompressed .cab file with ~350 files. I'd like to apply compression to it using command line tools. This seems to be straightforward task - use expand.exe to extract contents of the file into temporary folder, build ddf file from files in the folder and feed it to makecab.exe.

However things don't work as expected. If I build list of files for makecab.exe from temporary folder listing and create no compression .cab it appears to be larger than original .cab by 2Mb. This is an unpleasant surprise for me as I expected uncompressed .cab files produced from the same set of files to be equal.

Inspecting contents of two .cab files with 7Z GUI Archive Viewer uncovered that items in two .cab files are in different order. Also the first one contains 82 blocks and the second one 88 blocks.

This observation makes me believe ordering of items in ddf file affects output of makecab.exe.

I tried using `expand.exe -d` with hope that the tool will output list of entries in .cab file in the order they actually appear in the archive. However the tool outputs alphabetically sorted list of entries.

Questions:

- Is it possible to get list of entries in .cab file right in the order they appear in the archive with standard command line tools?
- Is it possible to instruct makecab.exe reorder files listed in ddf file for best layout?

My ddf file fragment:

```
.OPTION EXPLICIT
.Set Cabinet=ON
.Set GenerateInf=OFF
.Set CabinetFileCountThreshold=0
.Set FolderFileCountThreshold=0
.Set FolderSizeThreshold=0
.Set MaxCabinetSize=0
.Set MaxDiskFileCount=0
.Set MaxDiskSize=0
.Set ReservePerCabinetSize=0
.Set ReservePerDataBlockSize=0
.Set ReservePerFolderSize=0
.Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=
.Set ClusterSize=100000
.Set CabinetNameTemplate=C:\cygwin\tmp\radE7C61.cab
.Set Compress=OFF
"C:\cygwin\tmp\radCF764_core.cab.contents\File_003760a98ae0a9890833a40c14abcf3a" "File_003760a98ae0a9890833a40c14abcf3a" /INF=NO
"C:\cygwin\tmp\radCF764_core.cab.contents\File_00632a927382f2d81133ca36816174b7" "File_00632a927382f2d81133ca36816174b7" /INF=NO
"C:\cygwin\tmp\radCF764_core.cab.contents\File_008544959270414d85c069b9e9cdd1d6" "File_008544959270414d85c069b9e9cdd1d6" /INF=NO
"C:\cygwin\tmp\radCF764_core.cab.contents\File_0296ad9da2e43352229fd713f496db61" "File_0296ad9da2e43352229fd713f496db61" /INF=NO
```

**SOLVED**

My source .cab file was created with WiX and included a number of binary equal files. For such files WiX stores only one of them and other are just referenced. makecab.exe can't do this. makecab.exe can reorder input items for better performance, but it can't replace duplicated files with references.
So, different ordering of items in ddf file for makecab.exe doesn't make much sense, the tool will still produce larger files compared to what WiX can do if some items are duplicates.

Comment: You might want to check out: https://www.installaware.com/setup-squeezer.htm

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was trying to postprocess .cab produced by WiX. This didn't work out and is very bad idea in general. So I adjusted my WiX project to produce uncompressed and compressed .cab-s. Problem solved.

Comment: Given the context of Windows Installer, note that the [File table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596), ordered by  Sequence (and split according to the Media table), matches the [order of files in the cab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370558). The entries are named according to the File column.